# Split before decimal in django

Tags: django, django-templates

i have a variable which fetches the data from database

> {{i.rewardpoints}}

and the values it returns such as 1.799  or 12 the db has multiple values which contains decimals and without decimals

but i need to show the values  without decimals

how can i do this

Answer (score 2):

To round to nearest integer:

```
{{ i.rewardpoints|floatformat:"0" }}
```

To get the integer part:

```
{{ i.rewardpoints|stringformat:"d" }}
```

- [The floatformat filter documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat)
- [The stringformat filter documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat)

---

```
In [19]: tpl = Template('{{ x|stringformat:"d" }} {{ x|floatformat:"0" }}')

In [20]: tpl.render(Context({'x': 1.1}))
Out[20]: u'1 1'

In [21]: tpl.render(Context({'x': 1.9}))
Out[21]: u'1 2'
```

Comment: BUT IT HAS JUST ROUND OF THE VALUE , I DONT WANT THAT , I JUST WANT THE FIRST PART OF VALUE BEFORE DECIMAL